# How do I use express.js app.delete to remove a specific object from an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node and express to set up a server and do things like get, post, delete etc. But I can't figure out the way to delete by id. I know how to get the specific id but I can't figure out the last part.

Here's what I have so far. This is properly returning the obj.id.

```
app.delete("/api/notes/:id", function(req, res) {
    console.log("req params", req.params.id)
    
  });
```

Comment: This is not enough information to be able to answer the question. Is it a plain array you are trying to delete from? What does the array look like?

Comment: Is the entire question here really just "how do I delete an item from an array"?

Comment: How do you store your data?

Comment: `findByIdAndDelete`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array is just a standard array, the easiest way to remove an item from an array is to use `.filter()` to return a new copy of the array without the item you want to delete.

```
app.delete("/api/notes/:id", function(req, res) {
    console.log("req params", req.params.id)
    myArray = myArray.filter(({ id }) => id !== req.params.id);
  });
```

Otherwise, if you need to mutate (modify) the existing array, you can use `.findIndex()` and `.splice()` instead.

```
app.delete("/api/notes/:id", function(req, res) {
    console.log("req params", req.params.id)
    const itemIndex = myArray.findIndex(({ id }) => id === req.params.id);
    if (itemIndex >= 0) {
      myArray.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
  });
```